# How electrons move so fast in a electric circuit?

Tags: electricity, electronics

Whenever we switch on a bulb......it takes almost no time to glow up.....But we know that the atoms of a solid are tightly packed and there is a very little space between them.
So how the electrons travel through them irrespective of so much blockages in the conductor???

Comment: there's nothing special about the electron near your fingertips compared to the one at the lightbulb; either one can  light it up

Comment: _"We know that the atoms of a solid are tightly packed and there is a very little space between them..."_ > Actually, the space between atoms is **huge** when you compare it to how very tiny the nucleus of an atom is.

Comment: This post has two questions: the explicit "how do electrons flow through the wire" and the implicit "how does electricity work?" It's disappointing that the only answers to the explicit question are downvoted, and the upvoted answers only address the implicit question, and appear to be about direct current rather than alternating current.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The electrons themselves don't move all that fast. The wave energy is the part that moves quickly.

Picture it this way.

You have 500 meters of pipe, with a small hole at the other end. The pipe is full of water and you increase the pressure at your end. Water will flow out the other end immediately. This is the electrical energy (pressure) and the copper(water).

Now add some dye to the water and note how long it takes for the coloured water to come out the hole. The dye represents the new electrons, and they take noticeable time to move through the system. Pressure moves immediately.

(ok, in this case pressure moves at the speed of sound in water)

Comment: `in this case pressure moves at the speed of sound in water.`  What's the equivalent limiter for the movement of electrons in a circuit?

Comment: @MasonWheeler The conduction electrons are accelerated by the mostly-uniform electric field in the conductor; what limits their speed is the mean free paths between collisions with the fixed atoms on the lattice.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Electricity moves through conductors at some significantly-large fraction of the speed of light in a vacuum.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_electricity

Comment: Nice answer but your water pipe analogy doesn't fit very well with electric current. See the water doesn't just stay inside the pipe when both ends are open. Also (if you somehow make the water stay in pipe) when you apply pressure in one end, the water might absorb some pressure before propagating the pressure to other end since the water molecules are not that tightly bound. I would give "a metal rod in a metal tube" analogy.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's the answer to a slightly different question. As paul says, changes in the electric field of a conductor (analogous to pressure) propagate very quickly. The average drift velocity of the electrons is quite slow, a few centimeters per second.

Comment: @Ejay No analogy is perfect. The pipe has a small hole at the end; cover that with your finger, if you want to keep the water inside. Standard assumptions apply: the water is incompressible, the walls of the pipe perfecly rigid, you are in an inertial frame, it is not a leap-year, the horse running alongside the pipe is light and spherical, etc.

Comment: Ok, I _assume_ the analogy is right.

Comment: Am I missing something? This is an alternating current, so the electrons are just jiggling back and forth, not flowing through a 'tube'.

Comment: This answer seems a bit misleading.  Drake Marquis points out that actually, electrons travel incredibly fast compared to the velocity of their wave.  However, when we are talking about the latency between flipping the switch and electron drift through the lightbulb, the analogy of a fully primed tube is not far off, because there are many electrons bouncing around in the wire before the switch is flipped.

Comment: @MasonWheeler There actually is an equivalent limit, which is the speed of light in that medium, which is always slower than the speed of light in a vacuum.  This limit comes from the wave equations behind electrical and magnetic fields causing capacitance and inductance.  At those speeds, the effects seen are much more complicated than they seem in a simple lightbulb circuit.  Gigabit ethernet has to deal with these effects, as do radio circuits.

Comment: @CortAmmon The 'speed of electrons' referred to in this answer is their average drift speed, not their instantaneous speed. Yes, electrons are travelling really, _really_ fast, but that's mostly just orbiting nuclei. Their drift velocity through the medium is much slower than that. At least that's my understanding. Admittedly, it has been a few years since my chemistry/physics classes.

Comment: @reirab what is this orbital velocity you speak of?

Comment: @Aron Perhaps 'orbit' isn't the right word since the force involved isn't gravity, but, as far as I know, electrons do, in fact, tend to move in semi-circular paths around nuclei. See [atomic orbital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital). As I recall, the behavior in metals is somewhat different, though, with some of the electrons not necessarily paired to a particular nucleus.

Comment: @Hurkyl at 60Hz, the wavelength of electricity is 5000km, or about the width of Canada. Plenty of space for some electron flow.

Comment: @paul: That doesn't mean any individual electron ever drifts over a distance anywhere near that size. In fact, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity) says that they only travel a couple **micro**meters.

Comment: "Water will flow out the other end immediately" not correct my friend right, instanteneous actions is prohibited in relativity right, better to say "water will flow out the other end almost immediately"

Answer (score 14):

In fact, electron's speed is not so fast that light bulb glows up immediately. It is the electromagnetic field which travels in the circuit at near the speed of light that is resposible for it.

After turn on the light, electron only acquires a little speed in addition its thermal speed. The thermal speed of electron can be estimated by $mv^2/2\approx k_BT/2$, where $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant and $T$ is the absolute temperature and nearly 300 K. So the thermal speed is about 67.4 km/s.

In the electric field inside the circuit, the distance the electron travels freely before hitting the nucleus is estimated to about 300 nm in copper. If the voltage is 110 V, the speed increases by 86 m/s. In fact, the increase is the upper bound, because I assume the voltage change in 300 nm is 110 V, which is not true. Voltage changes over a much longer distance.

So you see, the increase in speed of electron is only about 86 m/s. The draft speed of electron is not really hight (compared to thermal speed).

Comment: Good answer. See more about the slow translational *drift* of electrons here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity

Answer (score 1):

Electrons can sneak pass all the atoms because of their wave function. They behave like waves not like particles. In short, because of quantum mechanics. In a periodic assembly of atoms like metallic solid they should not feel any resistance when moving through but because it is not perfectly periodic they feel aperiodic potential and this is why they scatter. They scatter on vibrations of atoms!
And, they move really fast but they have no definite direction. When you apply electric field to that metal, signal travels through the wire and all electrons practicly at once start moving in one direction, but slowly. This is known as drift speed. While they still move chaotically and with great speed, they slowly drift in one definite direction and it is this speed that that adds up to the original and still existing chaotic motion that is related to current and our harvesting energy of moving electrons.

Comment: Downvotes are intersting...what for? Simple question, simple answer...i believe it was enough.

Comment: this answer is OK as far as I see. I think it is the "sneak" that brought the downvotes. There are people fast-reading and filling in blanks as they see fit.

Comment: Why? Its a nice description and it is a way in which a scientist Bloch who invented Bloch functions described his wonder...

Answer (score -1):

You might be asking how metal is such an efficient conductor.

Some of the electrons move freely as a fluid.  They are not locked in place around the atoms, and don't need "room" in the classical sense.

[Here is a wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model) going over the real details.

> On a scale much larger than the inter atomic distance a solid can be viewed as an aggregate of a negatively charged plasma of the free electron gas and a positively charged background of atomic cores. The background is the rather stiff and massive background of atomic nuclei and core electrons which we will consider to be infinitely massive and fixed in space. The negatively charged plasma is formed by the valence electrons of the free electron model that are uniformly distributed over the interior of the solid

Comment: Why the negative votes??  It answers the question "how do the electrons travel...tightly packed atoms?" When the previous answers addressed only the *speed* of signal vs drift, which isn't really what the main point is.  Please leave **constructive criticism** on what you think is wrong, not just ding and run leaving no clue how I might improve the answer.  I see a similar -3 answer that also **answers** the real point rather than explaining drift vs pressure.